# Swift - Missing argument for parameter "coder" in call

Tags: ios, function, swift, arguments

Im am trying to pause or stop an SKAction that is being repeated forever which should happen when the user presses the pause button. I have found a way to stop the music but i cant call the function it is in because of this error. It says exactly: `Missing argument for parameter 'coder' in call`.

```
Class GameViewController: UIViewController, SwiftrisDelegate, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate     {

    @IBAction func didPause(sender: UIButton) {
        if self.scene.paused == false{
            self.scene.stopTicking()
            self.scene.paused = true
            GameScene().stopGameMusic() //error on this line
        }
    }
}

class GameScene: SKScene {

    runAction(SKAction.playSoundFileNamed("theme.mp3", waitForCompletion: true), withKey:("themeSong"))

    func stopGameMusic() {
        removeActionForKey("themeSong")
    }
 }
```

Comment: `GameScene()` creates a new instance of the class `GameScene`. Is it your intention to do that?

Comment: no, i didnt realise thats what it did. I am just trying to call the function within the GameScene class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no initializer for `GameScene` that takes no arguments - you haven't defined one nor is one inherited from `SKScene`.  If you intend to create a `GameScene` each time 'pause' is pushed, which is a questionable approach in itself, then you'll need to call an existing initializer or to create an initializer w/o any arguments.

It looks like the designated initializer for `SKScene` is `init(size: CGSize)`.  So instead of simply calling `GameScene()` call `GameScene(size: ...)` or, in the class `GameScene` define

```
class GameScene : SKScene {
  // ... 

  init () {
    super.init (size: ...)
  }
}
```

Comment: ok thanks for your help. Instead of creating a GameScene every time the button is pressed, do you know of another way that i could pause or stop the music when the button is pressed?

Comment: You create a `GameScene` one time, probably as part of your `GameViewController` and then you reference that one thereafter.  Of course, when you create it one time, you still need to use a proper initializer.  What the proper initializer is will depend on how your define the `GameScene` class.

Comment: So how do I properly initialize it? (please bear with me I am new to swift)

Comment: ah ok, yeah ive done that already i just didnt that it was called initializing. Ive sorted out the issue of creating a new instance of the scene but the code i am using to stop the skaction from running isnt workin. any help?

Comment: Mark this question as 'answered' and post another question with the details of the new problem.

Comment: i have posted a new question btw